# How to retainAll of List of Lists using stream reduce

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I faced following problem. I have a list of lists which i simply want to retainAll. I'm trying to do with streams

```
private List<List<Long>> ids = new ArrayList<List<Long>>();

// some ids.add(otherLists);  

List<Long> reduce = ids.stream().reduce(ids.get(0), (a, b) -> a.addAll(b));
```

unfortunately I got the error

```
Error:(72, 67) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    boolean cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Long>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

addAll returns a boolean, not the union of the two lists. You want

```
List<Long> reduce = ids.stream().reduce(ids.get(0), (a, b) -> {
    a.addAll(b);
    return a;
});
```

Answer (score 30):

If you want to reduce (I think you mean flatten by that) the list of lists, you should do it like this:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList

...

List<Long> reduce = ids.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(toList());
```

Using `reduce`, the first value should be the identity value which is not the case in your implementation, and your solution will produce unexpected results when running the stream in parallel (because `addAll` modifies the list in place, and in this case the identity value will be the same list for partial results).

You'd need to copy the content of the partial result list, and add the other list in it to make it working when the pipeline is run in parallel:

```
List<Long> reduce = ids.parallelStream().reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (a, b) -> {
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>(a);
    list.addAll(b);
    return list;
 });
```

Comment: Plus one for emphasizing the point about `reduce` requiring a proper identity value.

Comment: Or `collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll)` which is specifically designed for using mutable containers. However, the `flatMap` approach is much simpler.