# Merge all list values together in a map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to convert a Map like:

```
Map<String, List<String>>
```

to

```
List<String>
```

where the result list is the merge of all List values.

Comment: Answerers, please don't provide ready solutions for such questions. We *don't* want to encourage them here. Let's help OP by letting him try first by himself.

Comment: is not a ready solution, what mean that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826417/how-to-retainall-of-list-of-lists-using-stream-reduce/29826611

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just have

```
List<String> result = map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This retrieves the values of the map with [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) then flat maps each list into a Stream formed by its elements and collects the result into a list.

Another alternative, without flat mapping each list, and thus may be more performant, is to collect directly the `Stream<List<String>>` (returned by `values().stream()`) by calling `addAll` on each accumulated result.

```
List<String> result = map.values().stream().collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap` on the `Stream` of map entries :

```
List<String> list = map.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .flatMap(e->e.getValue().stream())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Eran: On a different note, does above statement result into creation of more temporary objects with each operation ( flatMap and collect )?

Comment: @Ravindrababu More temporary objects compared to what?

Comment: I mean, like Scala, map.flatMap() returning immutable collection and then collect() returning new set of immutable collection

Comment: @Ravindrababu I don't know Scala, and I'm not familiar with the internal implementation of the Stream pipeline, so I can't answer that.